# I installed Apache and added PHP to it, than installed MySql but PHPMYADMIN isn't working?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was using [XAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for windows but there were forming a lot of problems with [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/) so uninstalled it and installed [Apache Web Server](http://httpd.apache.org/). I connected Apache to [PHP](http://php.net/index.php) and it worked fine. I installed [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/) again and it worked fine.

Now I can not get [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/) to work with [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). I did not test PHP to see if it worked with [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/) without [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).

My PHPMYADMIN config.inc file:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 *
 * @version $Id: config.sample.inc.php 13111 2009-11-09 15:02:21Z lem9 $
 * @package phpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '***********'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/* rajk - for blobstreaming */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold'] = 50;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold'] = '32M';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout'] = 600;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold'] = '32M';

/* User for advanced features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

 /*
  * Directories for saving/loading files from server
  */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

The line that says `$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '***********'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */` doesn't really say that, I just don't want to share it. It only contains letters by the way.

PHP PHP.INI file:

I was too big to put on here. To see it look at the link:
http://ericlounge.host22.com/000/stack/php.ini

By the way: I am using Windows 7

Edit: Sorry for the lach of info. I was in a rush. I'm not anymore:

The error said:
Cannot load mysql extension. Please check your PHP configuration. - Documentation

My PHPINFO PAGE does not say anything about MySql but I might have missed it. I put the source into a page. Just follow the link below:
http://ericlounge.host22.com/000/stack/phpinfo.html

I did what pdjota said but I get the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\mysqltest.php on line 2

Comment: Have you changed the mysql password?  If you have, you need to change phpmyadmin config to reflect the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .php file that only contains

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

access that from a browser and see if php is configured with mysql support.

Your output from phpinfo should have a MySQL section, 
here is an example one yours should have similar mysql info
http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:Pto_DJIncV8J:www.entropy.ch/software/MacOSX/php/test.php+phpinfo&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

In Windows that means that PHP couldn't load the correct DLL.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function mysql_connect() in C:\Program
>   Files\Apache    Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\mysqltest.php
>   on line 2

In your PHPInfo, the extension_dir is set C:\php5
It seems that the php_mysql.dll is missing in that directory. Look for it in your installation and copy to c:\php5 or change your extension directory.

[For more info you ought to check the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)

Hi, it is difficult to tell without the actual error.
In you php.ini the
extension=php_mysql.dll
is set, so it may be ok. 
Check running as MindStalker said

```
   phpinfo();
```

to see if the extension is loaded actually, and then check mysql connection

```
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
  if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }else
        echo 'Connected successfully';
   mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: I did that. I edited the question with the info on the bottom. I was in a rush at the time but not anymore.